# Queryset evaluation sequence.  New-activity bit being overwritten unexpectedly

Tags: django

I am trying to display the old value of a db model field (`RelatedModel.new_reply`) after I save a new value to this field in the db.  The way this is supposed to work is the `new_reply` field marks a reply (by setting it to 1) as unread by the recipient (`rto`).  Once the recipient views the message, `new_reply` is reset to 0.  The template my_view.html displays a flag to the recipient if they have a new reply that they have not yet clicked on to view.  The first time the reply is viewed by the recipient, the flag `new_reply` is reset and subsequent views are not flagged as new.

The problem is that the line `response.save()` seems to change the value of `new_reply` in `d` in addition to the value stored in the db.  Therefore, the my_view.html never sees `new_reply==1`, only `new_reply==0`.  This seems very odd to me since `d` should be independent of the db once it is assigned.

Any ideas why this happens and how to fix it?

```
class ParentModel (models.Model):
    msg = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)

class RelatedModel (models.Model):
    msg = models.ForeignKey(ParentModel)
    reply = models.TextField()
    rto = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='rto')
    new_reply = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

def view_msg(request, msg_id):
    m = get_object_or_404(ParentModel, pk=id)
    r = m.RelatedModel_set.all()
    d = add_csrf(request, m=m, r=r) # d.r.new_reply==1 should be rendered
    # Once the view data is ready for rendering, clear the new_reply
    # bit.  If we do it earlier, we will not be able to mark replies as new.
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        for response in r:
            # Clear bit if current user is viewing reply addressed to them
            if (request.user == RelatedModel.rto):
                if response.new_reply == 1: # Is it a new reply?
                    response.new_reply = 0 # Reset the new_activity bits
                    response.save()
    return render_to_response('my_view.html',
                              {'db_data': d},
                              context_instance = RequestContext(request),
    )
```

Comment: I think this question comes down to when the querysets are evaluated.  I changed the `if response.new_reply == 1` statement to 'if response.new_reply==1:
    response.new_reply+=1
    response.save()
elif response.new_reply==2:
    response.new_reply=0'

Comment: Sorry about the above comment... wifi problems.  Here's the comment in full:
I think this question comes down to when the querysets are evaluated.  I changed the `if response.new_reply == 1` statement to 'if response.new_reply==1:
    response.new_reply+=1
    response.save()
elif response.new_reply==2:
    response.new_reply=0
    response.save()'
Then, in my view template I test for new_reply==2 instead of ==1.  This seems to work but is a hack.  Is there a better way?